# Create one general admin for multiple entities but call particular admin on edit

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

Lets assume i have a abstract doctrine entity class

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    private $title;
    private $description;
}
```

and two inherited child classes

```
class A extends BaseClass
{
}
```

and with an extra Field

```
class B extends BaseClass
{
    private $extraField;
    ...
}
```

For those two entities i want to create one admin for listing both together in one view. So in my admin.yml i add

```
AppBundle\Admin\BaseClassAdmin:
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: "base" }
      arguments:
        - null
        - AppBundle\Entity\BaseClass
        -
      calls:
        - [setSubClasses, [{'A' : 'AppBundle\Entity\A', 'B' : 'AppBundle\Entity\B'}]]
```

And the BaseClass Admin class is

```
class BaseClassAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('title');
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
    {
        $form->add('title');
        $form->add('description');
    }
}
```

What i want to do is that the listview displays both types which is not the problem. But when i click on one item which is of type B i want to show the extraField in my form. But it doesn't.

This is cause instead calling the particular admin for B (which has extraField added in form) its calling only the general admin (BaseClassAdmin).

So my question

Is there a way to call the particular admin corresponding to the type of the entity from the list view? Or is the only way to modify the BaseClassAdmin and solving it by adding ugly if-statements in the form method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `$this->getSubject()` in `configureFormFields`, and add fields conditionally based on an instanceof check.

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/advanced_configuration.html#inherited-classes

Comment: Ah okay, but theres no easy way to use the particular admin of the entity? If not, this will be the best answer

Comment: It has been a while since I used Sonata, I try to avoid it when I can. I remembered this, because I used this a lot in similar situations. There might be another way, but it wont be easy... nothing advanced is easy with sonata. And you will likely end up creating 2 classes and a lot of config lines to replace a simple if.

Answer (score 0):

What append if you add

```
$form->add('extrafield')
```

in your admin class ?

Comment: In my BaseClass admin the field get's added but i need it in condition of the entitytype added or not ...